# Spring framework - JPA based DAO: How should you add a Select Max(ID) method to a DAO definition

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Essentially I want to achieve something like:

```
package foo.bar.data.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import foo.bar.data.model.User;

public interface User extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

...

    @Query("SELECT NEW java.lang.Long(MAX(u.ID)) FROM USER u")
    //Long findMaxUserId();
    List<Long> findMaxUserId();
}
```

But without the List

Comment: add @Modifying annotation and you should specify return type to Long. should work ;)

Comment: also, don't name interface user, but userRepository, since User <- ambiguous

Comment: Nope, the immediate response of adding a @Modifying annotation is a complaint that a Modify query can only return an **int**. If you make that tweak you get a  org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Comment: are you calling this method from within @Transactional?